# How to bind an array inside a runtime class to a ListView?

Tags: xaml, uwp, c++-winrt

I have a class `car` with a member `IObservableVector<IInspectable> Wheel` that I would like to bind to a `ListView`.

Simple example here: https://github.com/maximebl/array_item_binding

When I run the program I get the error: `No such interface supported.`

Comment: I could not run your sample, it  miss `BlankApp1.vcxproj` file. Could you share a complete sample?

Comment: I just added the missing vcxproj file, thanks for checking it out

Comment: @mbl In the IDL of your cars, see if modify your code to IObservableVector<IInspectable> wheels{ get; }; works.